# Nest.js Testing Error: Using the "extends Logger" instruction is not allowed in Nest v8. Please, use "extends ConsoleLogger" instead

Tags: node.js, testing, nestjs, e2e-testing

Here's the problem I have:

I am using my custom Logger in Nest.js:

```js
export class ReportLogger extends ConsoleLogger {
  verbose(message: string) {
    console.log('【Verbose】Reporting', message);
    super.verbose.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  log(message: string) {
    console.log('【Log】Reporting', message);
    super.log.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

And the `log.interceptor.ts` file:

```
export class LogInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private reportLogger: ReportLogger) {
    this.reportLogger.setContext('LogInterceptor');
  }

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    const http = context.switchToHttp();
    const request = http.getRequest();

    const now = Date.now();
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        tap(() =>
          this.reportLogger.log(
            `${request.method} ${request.url} ${Date.now() - now}ms`,
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

And here's the `main.ts` file:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const reportLogger = new ReportLogger();

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    cors: {
      origin: ['http://localhost', 'http://localhost:3000'],
      credentials: true,
    },
    bufferLogs: true,
    logger: reportLogger,
  });

  app.useGlobalInterceptors(
    new LogInterceptor(reportLogger),
  );

  setupSwagger(app);

  await app.listen(4200);
}
```

When I run `npm run start:dev` to run the Nest App on dev, everything works fine. But when I run `npm run test:e2e` or `npm run test` on testing, it shows this error:

```
  Using the "extends Logger" instruction is not allowed in Nest v8. Please, use "extends ConsoleLogger" instead.

      10 |     const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      11 |       imports: [AppModule],
    > 12 |     }).compile();
         |        ^
      13 |
      14 |     app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
      15 |     await app.init();
```

I read the Nest.js doc again, and found the [Logging breaking change](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#logger-breaking-changes) in the docs. But the question is I have already made my ReportLogger extends ConsoleLogger, why this error shows again? And why it only shows in testing?

Comment: did you upgrade `@nestjs/testing` as well?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have faced the same problem after upgrading NestJS to version 8.

Later on, I found that package `@nestjs/testing` had previous version installed and was not upgraded to the latest version. The reason is, previous version of NestJS testing module is using the old Logger.

In order to fix this issue, you just need to upgrade the NestJS testing module.

**Run this command for Latest version:**

```
npm i @nestjs/testing@latest
```

OR **specific version**

```
npm i @nestjs/testing@8.0.6 // <--- Change the NestJS version here
```

After this, just build and run test cases again.

External Links:

- [NestJS Testing NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/testing)

Answer (score 0):

even with `"@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.7"` this issue still occurs

```
class Logger implements LoggerService { ... }

await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [ApiModule],
})
  .setLogger(new Logger())
  .compile();
```

setting logger instance solves that error on my side